# Do we have $e(\operatorname{rad}^2 A)=\operatorname{rad}^2 (e A)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $e$ be a primitive idempotent of $A$, where $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra over an algebraically closed field $K$. Do we have $e(\operatorname{rad}^2 A)=\operatorname{rad}^2 (e A)$? Here $\operatorname{rad}A$ is the radical of $A$. That is the intersection of all maximal  right ideals. This question is from Line 12 of the proof of Lemma 3.2 on page 60 of the book [Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras: Volume 1](http://books.google.com.hk/books/about/Elements_of_the_Representation_Theory_of.html?id=ayNHpi3tYhQC). It is said that $$e_a(\operatorname{rad}A)/e(\operatorname{rad}^2 A) \cong \operatorname{rad}(e_a A)/\operatorname{rad}^2 (e A).$$ Since $e_a (\operatorname{rad}A) = \operatorname{rad}(e_a A)$. I think that $e(\operatorname{rad}^2 A)=\operatorname{rad}^2 (e A)$. But I don't know how to prove this. Thank you very much.

Comment: you can use the same trick in the proof, write down a morphism $\mathrm{rad}eA \to e(\mathrm{rad}A)/e(\mathrm{rad}^2A)$ and see that this is surjective with kernel $\mathrm{rad}^2(eA)$.

Comment: @Aaron, thank you very much. But it seems that the kernel is $e(\operatorname{rad}^2 A)$ (not $\operatorname{rad}^2 (eA)$).

Comment: why not?  Anyway, $e \mathrm{rad}^n A = \mathrm{rad}^n(eA)$ can be shown simply by induction if you consider $\mathrm{rad}^{n-1}(A)$ as an $A$-module.  Note that by definition $\mathrm{rad}M=MJ(A)$ for any (right) $A$-module.  Now $e(\mathrm{rad}^n A) = e \mathrm{rad}^n A = \mathrm{rad}^{n-1}(eA)J(A) = (e\mathrm{rad}^{n-1} A)J(A)$ by induction, then keep on doing this you get $(eA)J(A)^n = \mathrm{rad}^n(eA)$ at the end.

Comment: @Aaron, thank you very much. I am confused about the definition of $\operatorname{rad}^2 A$. I think that $\operatorname{rad}^2 A$ consists of all elements of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i$, where $n$ is a positive integer and $x_i, y_i \in \operatorname{rad}A$. By your comment above, it seems that $\operatorname{rad}^2 A$ is the radical of $\operatorname{rad} A$. Are these two definitions the same?

Comment: radical of a radical is a more natural definition, but the two are the same, yes.  It's more or less due to Nakayama's Lemma.  (I only consider finite dimensional algebra, not sure about infinite dimensional one)

Comment: @Aaron, thank you very much.

Comment: @Aaron, thank you very much. I am trying to show that $\operatorname{rad}(\operatorname{rad}(A))=(\operatorname{rad} A)^2$. Since $\operatorname{rad} A)^2$ is an nilpotent ideal of $\operatorname{rad}A$ and $\operatorname{rad}(\operatorname{rad}(A))$ is the maximal ideal of $\operatorname{rad}A$, we know that $(\operatorname{rad} A)^2 \subseteq \operatorname{rad}(\operatorname{rad}(A))$. But how to prove that $\operatorname{rad}(\operatorname{rad}(A)) \subseteq (\operatorname{rad} A)^2$?

Comment: @Aaron, I proposed a new question about this problem.

Comment: @Aron, I proposed a [new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367909/question-about-the-radical-of-the-jacobson-radical) about this problem.